# showing and hiding DIV using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the below code in my ASP (CLassic) page (part of a page with dozens of checkboxes set from the db):

```
<tr height="30px">
        <td class="summarytext">Show Gender Pay Gap Options</td>
        <td class="formtext">
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="chkDisplayGPGOptions" <%if g_blnchkDisplayGPGOptions = True then Response.Write("checked")%>>
        </td>
    <td colspan="7">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
            <input type="button"  class="help" align="left" id="Button3" onmousemove="javascript:DisplayHelp(150,-160, 10, 'HELP', 'Select if you want to exclude this pay type in netpay for attachment calculations.', this)" onmouseout="javascript:HideHelp()" WIDTH="16px" HEIGHT="16px">
    </td>
    <DIV id="divGPGOptiona" style="display:none">
        <table>
            <tr height="30px">
                <td class="summarytext">Include Bonus in calculation for GPG reporting</td>
                <td class="formtext">
                        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="chkIncludeBonusInGPG" <%if g_blnchkDisplayGPGOptions = True then Response.Write("checked")%>>
                </td>                                                    
            </tr>
            <tr height="30px">
                <td class="summarytext">Include Gross Pay in calculation for GPG reporting</td>
                <td class="formtext">
                        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="chkIncludeGrossPayInGPG" <%if g_blnchkDisplayGPGOptions = True then Response.Write("checked")%>>
                </td>                                                    
            </tr>
        </table>
    </DIV>
</tr>
```

what I'd like to do is show and hide the DIV `divGPGOptiona` when the checkbox `chkDisplayGPGOptions` is checked...

Is there was some way of using just CSS for this, or will I need to do this with JavaScript and the DOM?

Comment: Gotta use some jquery to make it happen.

Comment: Not necessarily jQuery but you will need some JS to do this. There's no clear, close relationship between the two elements that you could map using CSS.

Comment: You can do it, only if the div is a child

Comment: Possible with css alone, if you can change the html structure to make the div `chkDisplayGPGOptions` placed right next to the checkbox. Or some other structure which makes it possible to select the div based on checkbox using css selector.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that represents "hide" state and toggle it when checkbox changes.

See how:

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[name="check"]');
var div = document.querySelector('#container');

checkbox.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
   if (div.classList.contains('is-hide')) {
      div.classList.remove('is-hide');
   } else {
      div.classList.add('is-hide');
   }
});
```

```css
.is-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="check" />

<div id="container">Here goes the content.</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to toggle the display with JavaScript. You don't need jQuery for this. It can be done in native JavaScript.

```js
var checkBox = document.getElementById("check-box");
var myDiv = document.getElementById("my-div");
myDiv.style.display = "none";

checkBox.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (myDiv.style.display == "none") {
        myDiv.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        myDiv.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="my-div">This is a div</div>

<p>The div above is hidden by default. Click the checkbox to toggle on and off</p>

<input id="check-box" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: Thanks but what if I have dozens of checkboxes, and only want this to work on once called `chkDisplayGPGOptions`

Answer (score 2):

CSS Code:

`.hidden{
       display: none;
    }`

html Code:

```
 <DIV id="divGPGOptiona" class="hidden" >
```

Jquery Code:

```
    $(".checkbox").on('click',function(){
         if($(".checkbox").prop("checked")){
            $("#divGPGOptiona").removeClass("hidden");
         }
        else{
          $("#divGPGOptiona").addClass("hidden");
        }
     });
```

Comment: what if I have dozens of checkboxes, and only want this to work on once called `chkDisplayGPGOptions`

Comment: If you write class = "checkbox-one" for outer checkbox then you may deal dozens of checkboxes containing same class name.Moreover if you use <DIV id="divGPGOptiona" class="hidden" > then other checkboxes would be hidden.You do not have to face any conflict for checkbox's class name.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pure CSS using the siblings `+` selector.

So this can be done if you have the div as a sibling of the checkbox. In order for you to replicate, you would need to change your HTML structure. Which is advised, because you are placing a `div` inside a table row `<tr>`, without a table cell. Why?

```css
.checkboxSibling {
  display: none;
}

/*.checkbox:checked + .checkboxSibling {
  display: block;
 }*/

input[name="chkDisplayGPGOptions"]:checked + .checkboxSibling {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Input 1 -
  <input class="checkbox" name="chkDisplayGPGOptions" type="checkbox"/>
  <div class="checkboxSibling">Checkbox Checked</div>
</div>

<div>
  Input 2 -
  <input class="checkbox" name="someOtherName" type="checkbox"/>
  <div class="checkboxSibling">Checkbox Checked</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but what if I have dozens of checkboxes, and only want this to work on once called `chkDisplayGPGOptions`

Comment: you can either set a `class` to be that, or use the css selector `input[name="chkDisplayGPGOptions"` for your input. This way you can get as specific as you like, to avoid this happening for unnecessary elements.